# Is fstab syntax the same as mount?

Tags: mount, fstab

I would like to mount a filesystem permanently. If I understand this correctly, it can be done by adding a line to `/etc/fstab`.

If my mount syntax is like this:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=USERNAME,password=PASSWD //192.168.1.88/shares /mnt/share
```

Then, what must I add to `fstab` to make it work properly?

Comment: do you mean editing by doing `vi /etc/fstab`?

Comment: The file is `/etc/fstab`. There is an editor named `vi`, that some people will try to get you to use. Unless you use an editor a lot, and are prepared to spend some time learning then keep away from `vi`.

Comment: In Unix filename capitalisation matters, so I fixed this in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `man fstab` for the details on the fields. In short your line will be:

```
//192.168.1.88/shares  /mnt/share  cifs  username=USERNAME,password=PASSWD 0 0
```

See also `man mount.cifs`, especially the `credentials=` directive to keep the credentials apart from the fstab file.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question and for the tip on using credentials= . I'm new to unix but look forward to learning.

Comment: You are welcome and good luck learning a new OS. You may consider to accept the answer if it solved your question.